# Can we add script links such as css,js in common include header.php file?

Tags: php, html, script-tag

I have a common php header file (header.php) that contains navigation links, which is pulled into all other web pages by using `include_once <?ob_start();'../include/header.php'; ?>`.

However, around 20 more web pages are having common css and js link files. Can we take these css & js into header.php the same way we do with the navigation, to save our time while we are adding further more script links and modifications?

Comment: are you trollin'?

Comment: Regret. Nothing to troll Jason. Its truly serious with hidden answer for 'will it affect SEO?'

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but you will also need to include the head tags which are supposed to contain your script links.

Actually you can put all your code from html tag to the end of the navigation bar into your header.php file. The same for the footer, so that your 20 web pages contain only their main content.

Be careful with the url of your css/js files. The easiest way is to use absolute urls to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, if we have 2 head tags (one on webpages with meta tags, keywords and others on include headers/footers for css,js scripts), will it perfect on all the browsers as well as any problem on SEO may happen?

Comment: Yes, no problem with SEO or display, as your include function will put everything together before sending the output to the browser.